# use url in flash list

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

So i have a service that passes a list of citys according to a request that is made against it what i need to do is to add the url to click on each row i have tried outerDocument parentDocument but wasnt able to get it with them heres an example of the list i would like to modify

```
 <s:List includeIn="data" x="28" y="10" width="312" height="255" id="list" labelField="city" >
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getCitysResult.lastResult}"/>
 </s:List>
```

this is the data thats been fed to the list

```
   object[]
     [0]
    citycode:034957
    id:20
    countrycode:GB
    url:http://example.com
    city:lincoln
     [1]...............
```

is there anyway using this list i can use the url thats in each object for the click on each row i aslo tried using a datagrid with buttons inside the rows but i still couldnt get the url to link to the button or row

Comment: Do you want to open a Browser Popup with the URL target? Or do you want to display the page inside your flex application?

Comment: i want it to open up a page in the browser go to the url in the same window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigateToUrl(new URLRequest(data.url), "_blank"); to keep opening a new browser window for each one or navigateToUrl(new URLRequest(data.url), "myWindowName"); to attempt to have the OS re-use the same named browser window.